# How to refresh the displayed window of imshow?

Tags: opencv

Every time I click on the displayed window, I want a circle to be drawn. The following code does not refresh the window. How to do so?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

const string filename = "family.jpg";
const string sourceWindow = "source";

void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    Mat* image = reinterpret_cast<Mat*>(param);
    switch (event)
    {
    case cv::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cout << "at (" << x << "," << y << ") values is: "
            << static_cast<int>(image->at<uchar>(Point(x, y))) << endl;
        circle(*image, Point(x, y), 65, 0, 5);
        break;
    }
}

void main()
{
    Mat src = imread(filename, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    if (!src.empty())
    {
        namedWindow(sourceWindow, WINDOW_NORMAL);
        imshow(sourceWindow, src);
        setMouseCallback(sourceWindow, onMouse, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&src));
    }
    waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: You need to call `imshow` again after you've modified the image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as it is done for video capturing (see [VideoCapture](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html#videocapture))

You simply call `imshow`again with the new image.

```
void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    Mat* image = reinterpret_cast<Mat*>(param);
    switch (event)
    {
    case cv::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cout << "at (" << x << "," << y << ") values is: "
            << static_cast<int>(image->at<uchar>(Point(x, y))) << endl;
        circle(*image, Point(x, y), 65, 0, 5);
        imshow(sourceWindow, image);
        break;
    }
}
```